# Cannot convert IEnumerable<Class1> to IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#

The following code will get two errors on parameter `p1` and `p2` of method call `NewMethod<T>(p1, p2);`.

1. `p1`: Cannot convert `IQueryable<ICollection<Class1>>` to `IQueryable<ICollection<T>>`?
2. `p2`: Cannot convert `IEnumerable<Class1>` to `IEnumerable<T>`

How to fix the method call?

```
public interface IBase<out T> { T Prop1 { get; } }
class Class1 : IBase<int> { public int Prop1 { get; set; } }

static IEnumerable<T> NewMethod<T, U>(IQueryable<ICollection<T>> exist, IEnumerable<T> bs)
where T : IBase<U>
{
    return null;
}

public IEnumerable<T> Existed<T>(IEnumerable<T> p2) 
{
  .....
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(Class1)) {
    IQueryable<ICollection<T>> p1 = null;
    return result = NewMethod<Class1, int>(p1, p2);
  } .....
}
```

Is it a co-variance or contra-variance issue?

Comment: When you call `NewMethod<T>(p1, p2)` the parameters must be of type `IQueryable<ICollection<T>>` and `IEnumerable<T>`. If you called `NewMethod<Class1>(p1, p2)`, that would work, but then you'd get similar error from trying to return `IEnumerable<Class1>` as `IEnumerable<T>`. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the repeated code blocks which only diff by types.

Comment: I do that often, too, but what you've failed to understand here is that for the compiler `Class1` is a totally different type than the generic `T` and they cannot be casted to one another. You could call `NewMethod<Class1, int>(p1, p2)` like I already said in my first comment, but it would fail when trying to compile the return. Why do you use explicit class, when your parameter and return types are generic?

Comment: Why is `Existed` generic when it only works with one type? An `IEnumerable<Class1>` is not an `IEnumerable<T>` for _all_ possible `T` which is what a generic parameter signifies.

Comment: @Lee I didn't list all other cases. One is enough to show the error.

Comment: The other cases won't work for the same reason. There isn't enough information to answer this without showing what the callers look like. What is the `bands` parameter for when it isn't used inside `Existed`?

Comment: @Lee The bottom method is the caller. I removed the function header to better indicate it.

Comment: Your updated code now compiles.

Comment: Here's a minimized reproduction of what I see as the essential problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/xkpsgI

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It needs several type casting.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Existed<T>(IEnumerable<T> p2) // where T : IBase<U>
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(Class1)) {
    IQueryable<ICollection<T>> p1 = null;
    return NewMethod<Class1, int>( // Type parameter are assigned
        p1 as IQueryable<ICollection<Class1>>,
        p2 as IEnumerable<Class1>
    ) as IEnumerable<T>;
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: This is not an inference failure - a `Class1` is not a `T` for any `T` so the compiler is right to reject it. Generic methods should behave uniformly for its type parameters which this does not do, which is why you need the cast. However this cannot work for all possible types `T` since there are potentially an infinite number of such types.

Comment: The `Existed` method has no idea what `T` will be when called, only the client can know it will provide `Class1` as a parameter. If some other client uses a different type for `T` your cast will fail. That is why the compiler requires you to cast, because you are performing a narrowing conversion from all possible `T` to one particular type you have chosen in advance.

Comment: The cast of the return value is required because `NewMethod<Class1, int>` returns an `IEnumerable<Class1>` which is _not_ an `IEnumerable<T>`. This is the same reason you need to cast `p1` and `p2` - by picking a particular type for `T` you are performing a narrowing conversion. What do you expect to happen if `T = Class2`? Your cast will fail since you are assuming `T = Class1` which does not hold in general. Generic methods must work for _all_ possible types `T` while the client need only pick one. The compiler is telling you this which you are hacking around with a cast.

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer:

The OP originally asked a question about why generics were not working with `ICollection<T>`. After I answered, the OP changed to ask different questions about `IEnumerable<T>`, so this answer no longer applies.

> Is it a co-variance or contra-variance issue?

Yes, since `ICollection<T>` is not covariant, the compiler cannot substitute `Class1` for `IBase<U>`.

Try using `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>` (`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant).

Why can't you do this?

```
public IEnumerable<T> Existed<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> bands) where T : IBase<U> {
  IQueryable<IEnumerable<T>> p1 = null;
  IEnumerable<T> p2 = null;
  return NewMethod<T, U>(p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: Changed to `IEnumerable` but still get the similar error. `p2` is IEnumerable.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 `p2` is not an `IEnumerable`, it (covariantly) is an `IEnumerable<IBase<U>>`. It still does not compile because the compiler cannot validate that `Class1` is an `IBase<U>` -- it's not, it is an `IBase<int>`.

Comment: IColllection is unrelated to the issue. I will answer the question.